# Reference to a pointer - Polymorphism

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

If I am **NOT** using a reference to a pointer when sending the base-pointer to another class constructor - *and* in this class binding the basepointer to a derived object of the base - the basepointer returns NULL.

Simply - what is the reason for this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
   public:
      virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Sub1 : public Base {
public:
   void print() {
      cout << "I am allocated!\n";
  }
};

class App {
public: 
   App(Base *b) {
      b = new Sub1;
   }
};

int main() {
   Base *b;
   b = NULL;

   App app(b);

   if (b != NULL)
      b->print();
   else
      cout << "Basepointer is NULL\n";

   return 0;
}
```

The crucial part here is the signature of the App-class constructor

when not using a reference to the basepointer i.e

```
   App(Base *b)
```

the output is:

```
   Basepointer is NULL
```

And when using a reference to the base-class i.e.

```
  App(Base *&b)
```

the output is:

```
 I am allocated!
```

Comment: In short: google "pass by value" and "pass by reference".

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the pointer *by value*, this means that the value is copied, and in the function you only modify the copy. Modifying a copy will of course not modify the original.